# why do I need 8 backslashes?

Tags: javascript, proxy, escaping, cgi, xss

While writing a "simple" cgi shell script proxy server to wrap quoted xml in a jsonp-style callback, I ran into an issue with escaping the backslashes (that was solved through trial and error and Opera's excellent debugger).  I am still trying to figure out why the extra set of backslashes is needed (8 vs. 4).  I'm given to understand that with each parse you need to double the number of backslashes, but either I seem to be overlooking an iteration somewhere, or misunderstand the handling.  Does it get parsed twice in the browser?

*this is the final working code that I am trying to figure out why it works*

```
#!/bin/sh
CB=${QUERY_STRING%%&*}
URL=${QUERY_STRING#*&}
case "$CB" in
    callback=*)
        printf "Content-type: application/javascript\r\n\r\n${CB##*=}(\""
        wget -q --no-check-certificate -U "NetSurf/2.9 (Linux; i686)" -T 20 -O - "$URL" \
            |tr -c [\ -~] " "|sed "s/[\\]/\\\\\\\\/g;s/[\"]/\\\\\"/g"
        printf "\")"
        ;;
    *)exit;;
esac
```

Here is the test page that I am using (Edit - replaced with simpler non-gzip version).

```
<html><head><title>test</title></head><body><div id="notaniframe"></div>
<script>
    function dummy(data){document.getElementById("notaniframe").innerHTML=data}
    Loaded=0
    setTimeout(function(){if(!Loaded)alert("load failed")},30000);
</script>
<script onload='Loaded=1' src="http://localhost/cgi-bin/xml2jsonp.cgi?callback=dummy&http://stackoverflow.com"></script>
</body></html>
```

*This just crams stackoverflow.com into a div*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One pass is performed by Bash; this command:

```
sed "s/[\\]/\\\\\\\\/g;s/[\"]/\\\\\"/g"
```

runs this `sed` script:

```
s/[\]/\\\\/g;s/["]/\\"/g
```

One pass is performed by `sed`; in the replacement-string, `\\` means `\`. So this `sed` script will replace `\` with `\\` and `"` with `\"`. As you wanted. (Note that the square-brackets around `"` don't actually do anything here, and the square-brackets around `\` are equivalent to escaping it with another `\`.)

You can remove one set of backslashes by using single-quotes rather than double-quotes in your Bash script; inside single-quotes, `\` has no special meaning. In other words, you can change this:

```
sed "s/[\\]/\\\\\\\\/g;s/[\"]/\\\\\"/g"
```

to this:

```
sed 's/[\]/\\\\/g;s/["]/\\"/g'
```

or, for that matter, to this:

```
sed 's/\\/\\\\/g;s/"/\\"/g'
```

Comment: `sed 's/[\]/\\\\/g;s/["]/\\"/g'` was exactly what I was missing, I don't know why I used double quotes with sed this time.  Thanks.